# SQL server optimization Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I have below Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColA,ColB AS S 
   from TableA  
   where ColA <> 0        
   AND CONCAT(ColA,ColB) NOT IN (
                                   SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(ColA,ColB) from TableB
                                   WHERE ColB <> 0
                                )
```

Table `TableA` has about `200000` of records and

Table `TableB` has about `50000` records

When I am running this query it is taking too much time about 2 minutes.

How can I optimize this query to reduce execution time?

What should I do to optimize this query?

Comment: Please post the execution plan as xml, table schema with some sample data

Comment: You have 2 ANDs in `ColA <> 0 AND  AND CONCAT`

Comment: Are cols numbers? Are you sure concatenating them? `select concat (a,b) 
from (select 11 as a, 2 as b
     union all 
     select 1, 12) t
     where concat (a,b) ='112'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this....

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ColA, A.ColB AS S 
from TableA  A
where A.ColA <> 0 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                from TableB B
                WHERE B.ColB <> 0
                AND A.ColA= B.ColA
                AND A.ColB = B.ColB)
```

*Note*

I dont know much about your table schema or indexes but I know one thing for sure that the expression `CONCAT(ColA,ColB)` is not Sargable. Write the same query a bit differently and it will much quicker if there are in indexes on the columns `ColA` and `ColB`.

Comment: In theory, your query could bring incorrect results. In your case `CONCAT(ColA, ColB)` would be equals to `CONCAT(ColB, ColA)`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT` will rule out any index seeks on your columns in both tables.

If the primary purpose of your query is to find all ColA,ColB combinations which are in `TableA` and not in `TableB`, you can try something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColA,ColB AS S 
FROM TableA  
WHERE ColA <> 0
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableB
    WHERE TableB.ColA = TableA.ColA
    AND TableB.ColB = TableA.ColB 
    AND TableB.ColB <> 0
   )
```

***Note:** This should result in a better execution plan than your current query however its hard to comment without your actual execution plan and existing table structure and indexes*

Answer (score 0):

Use [set operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188055(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
SELECT ColA, ColB FROM TableA WHERE ColA <> 0
EXCEPT
SELECT ColA, ColB FROM TableB WHERE ColB <> 0
```

No `DISTINCT` needed cause `EXCEPT` do this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColA,ColB AS S
FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB 
    ON TableA.ColA = TableB.ColA
      and TableA.ColB = TableB.ColB
WHERE TableA.ColA <> 0
    and TableB.ColB <> 0
    and TableB.ColB is null
```

Answer (score 0):

As some posters have pointed out, you will need to use the CONCAT instead of the querying on ColA and ColB independently to get the correct data.

If this is an important enough query to merit its own index, or CONCAT(ColA, ColB) is commonly used data. You could look into creating a computed column for CONCAT(ColA, ColB) and an index on that computed column.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.ColA, A.ColB
    FROM TableA A 
    LEFT JOIN TableB B 
    ON B.CONCAT(ColA,ColB) = A.CONCAT(ColA,ColB)
    WHERE A.ColA <> 0
    and B.ColB <> 0
    and B.ColB is null
```

I have also had luck filtering down using CTEs and then doing any computations last, to make best use of the indexes that are currently on the table.

```
    WITH FilteredA as (
    select ColA, ColB
    from tableA 
    WHERE ColA <> 0 ), 

    FilteredB as (
    select ColA, ColB
    from tableB 
    WHERE ColB <> 0 ) 

    SELECT DISTINCT FilteredA.*
    from FilteredA 
    LEFT JOIN FilteredB ON FilteredA.ColA = FilteredB.ColB
    AND FilteredA.ColB = FilteredB.ColB
    WHERE FilteredA.CONCAT(ColA,ColB) = FilteredB.CONCAT(ColA,ColB)
```